# Is it possible to use environments from existing packages when defining my own custom environment?

Tags: macros, listings, environments

I'm trying to define a new environment for my own needs, and I'm trying to use the `lstlisting` environment from the `listings` package in the definition of my new environment, but whenever I try to compile my document with this definition nothing happens. I don't get any errors, but the document also doesn't recompile. When I remove the `lstlisting` environment from my definition however the document compiles without any issues.

In more detail:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\newenvironment{java}
    {
    \ttfamily
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=java]
    }
    {
    \end{lstlisting}
    \sffamily
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{java}
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    System.out.println("This is a Test!");
}
\end{java}

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this nothing happens.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\newenvironment{java}
    {
    \ttfamily
    \begin{center}
    }
    {
    \end{center}
    \sffamily
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{java}
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    System.out.println("This is a Test!");
}
\end{java}

\end{document}
```

This works perfectly fine and compiles without issues, though it (obviously) doesn't do what I want it to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=java]
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    System.out.println("This is a Test!");
}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

This works fine too, except it also doesn't do what I need.

Comment: verbatim environments like listings require special handling, the listings package comes with special environment declarations to declare extended environments see `texdoc listings`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5clstnewenvironment

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! `\lstnewenvironment` worked!

Comment: It's easier to search the site once you know the answer:-)